# Python 3.x При работе с двумерным массивом выдает "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, массивы, append

Итак, поставил себе задачу сделать симулятор жизни народа. Это блок, который отвечает за его рождение, взросление и смерть. Решил использовать двумерный массив, в котором первая строчка отвечает за мужчин, вторая за женщин и третья за детей.

```
import random
i = 0
j = 0
nar = [[18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18],
   [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
wm = len(nar)  # количество всех людей
wmng = 0   # количество людей, способных сделать ребенка (они же не будут с 4 детьми на руках делать еще сколько же)
# для статистики 
star = 0
sredn = 0
mlad = 0
l = 0

# перебор года
for k in range(1, 101):

# старение и смерть людей
for i in reversed(range(len(nar))):
    for j in reversed(range(len(nar[i]))):
        nar[i][j] += 1
        if nar[i][j] > 59:
            del nar[i]
            wm -= 1
print("1 is finished")

# рождение детей
for i in range(wm // 2):
    for rnd in range(random.randint(2, 4)):
        nar[2].append(0)
    wm -= 2
    wmng += 2
print("2 is finished")

# взросление детей
for j in reversed(range(len(nar[2]))):
    if nar[2][j] > 17:
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
            nar[0].append(18)
            wm += 1
            del nar[2][j]
        else:
            nar[1].append(18)
            wm += 1
            del nar[2][j]
print("3 is finished")

if k % 5 == 0: # каждые 5 лет список "рентабельных к новым детям" обновляется
    wm += wmng
    wmng = 0
print(l)
l = 0
print("--------------------------------------------------------- ", k)

# статистика
for i in reversed(range(len(w))):
    if w[i] > 44:
        star += 1
    if w[i] <= 44:
        sredn += 1
print(len(w))
print(len(ch))
print(star, "   ", sredn, "   ", len(ch), "   ", len(m), "   ", len(w), "       ", len(w) + len(ch) + len(m))
```

Изначально делал в три списка, но для оптимизации решил сделать двумерным массивом, что вызвало некоторые трудности. На 42 году жизни народца программа выдает ошибку `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Евгений/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/experiment.py", line 33, in <module>
    for j in reversed(range(len(nar[2]))):
IndexError: list index out of range`

Помогите, всю голову уже изломал. Знаю, что многое из этого неправильно и неэстетично, прошу подсказать, где можно оптимизировать. Этот яп учу вторую неделю, до этого использовал только паскаль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На 42 итерации у вас первый раз срабатывает эта конструкция:

```
...
if nar[i][j] > 59:
    del nar[i]
...
```

которая удаляет из переменной nar элементы. В результате этого список становится короче. 
После этого при обращение ко второму его элементу происходит ошибка, так как второго элемента теперь нет.

```
for j in reversed(range(len(nar[2])))
```

Вероятно стоит заменить `del nar[i]` на `del nar[i][j]`